# Spacy training error:IndexError: [E009] The `update` method expects same number of docs and golds, but got: 7 docs, 9 golds

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, spacy, training-data

This is my code for name entity recognition using spacy.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en")
text = "But YouTube is starting from behind. The company made a late push\ninto hardware, and Apple’s Siri, available on iPhones, and Amazon’s Alexa\nsoftware, which runs on its Echo and Dot devices, have clear leads in\nconsumer adoption."
doc = nlp(text)
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text,ent.label_)
```

Output:

```
YouTube ORG
Apple’s Siri ORG
iPhones ORG
Amazon ORG
Echo and Dot ORG
```

In NER model of the spacy YouTube is label ORG but I want to update the **Youtube as Community** for my project.
To update this I follow this official documentation of spacy https://spacy.io/usage/training and update in the following way:

```
new_nlp = spacy.blank('en')
optimizer = new_nlp.begin_training()
new_nlp.update('YouTube', 'Community', sgd=optimizer)
```

I am getting the following error when update:

```
IndexError: [E009] The `update` method expects same number of docs and golds, but got: 7 docs, 9 golds.
```

Please tell me what is going wrong and how can I update Youtube in the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

In the docs you can see the `update` expects an iterable: `nlp.update([doc], [gold], drop=0.5, sgd=optimizer)`

So the fix is just to put the words in lists:

```
new_nlp.update(['YouTube'], ['Community'], sgd=optimizer)
```

But you might still wonder *why* the error looked like that. ;) It's because string itself is an iterable! When you iterate over a string, it yields each character - and `'YouTube'` has 7 characters while `'Community'` has 9, so that gives "`7 docs, 9 golds`"

Comment: I have updated nlp.update([doc], [gold], drop=0.5, sgd=optimizer) still getting same error. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Please read the docs you provided yourself. It seems that it does not only expect an iterable, but an iterable of specific types - docs and golds. See example on the right - https://spacy.io/api/language#update

Answer (score -1):

new_nlp.update([json.loads(Youtube)],[json.loads(Community)], sgd=optimizer)

Comment: It will make this answer more useful if there is an explanation of what is going on, in addition to the code snippet. "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer Also, if you wrap your code snippet with \`\`\`, it makes things more readable.